# How to cast observable response to local object

Tags: javascript, angular

In current Angular 6 application there is a subscribe to observable (response from RESTful service)

```
  this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({bag}) => {
    console.log(bag);
    this.bag= bag;
  });
```

the subscription is waiting response from resolver

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BagResolver implements Resolve<Bag> {
  constructor(private service: BagService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const id = route.params['id'] ? route.params['id'] : null;
    if (id) {
      const existingBag = this.service.find(id).pipe(map((bag: HttpResponse<Bag>) => bag.body));
      return existingBag;
    }

    return of(new Bag());
  }
}
```

Ran a debug mode I found bag is an object with follow structure

```
Object
{headers:,
 body{id:10, name:aName, ...},  <-- this is the actual bag object
 statusCode:"OK",
 statusCodeValue:"200"
 }
```

So `bag` in the subscription is not really a bag object but looks like a http response which wrapped the bag object in its body

Now I really want to extract the `body` from above object and cast to local object

So then how to safely extract the data and cast the object from above return from subscribe(...)?

Comment: Interesting... Any chance you are using Spring?

Comment: @Rafael that's right the webservices are created by Spring boot

Comment: If I am incorrect, I'd need to see the implementation of `this.service.find(id)` for further investigation. My base assumption is that your service is observing the response body.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this object is a [ResponseEntity from Spring](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.java) and *not a HttpResponse from angular.* The tell is `statusCodeValue` which is not a property of angular's HttpResponse. If you are serializing spring ResponseEntitys and sending them as the response AND observing the response `body` (indirectly or directly—which all appear true here), you need to create a similar interface in the front-end and use it in your service:

```js
interface ResponseEntity<T> {
   headers: { [headerName: string]: string },
   body: T,
   statusCode: "OK" | "SERVER_ERROR" | "BAD_REQUEST", //etc
   statusCodeValue: "200" | "500" | "400" | "404" //etc
}
```

Sample Service

```
import { ResponseEntity } from "./dir/dir/file";

class BagService {
    constructor(http: HttpClient) {}

    find(id: string): Observable<Bag> {
        return this.http.get<ResponseEntity<Bag>>(`/bag/${id}`).pipe(
            map(resp => resp.body)
        );
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would sugest that you don't subscribe in the TypeScript and use the async pipe in the view

```
bag$ = this.activatedRoute.data.pipe(
    map(res => res.body) // This will map your data to extract the body
);
```

in your TypeScript and in your view

```
<div *ngIf="bag$ | async as bag">
    {{bag | json}}
</div>
```

That is what the async pipe is for and you don't have to worry about managing subscriptions.

Comment: thank you but unfortunately I have to do some process of the bag object before throw/bind it to html

Comment: Then do it in the map function, that is what map is for.

Comment: Interestingly, it subscribe to a resolver that actually do the pipe work, I just updated the ticket

Comment: I think the subscription itself make the end object wrapped in a http response when passing to the subscriber. Otherwise why the resolver returned the body already but from subscriber it is still wrapped in HttpResponse

Comment: I also got ``TS2559: Type 'Observable<any>' has no properties in common with type 'Bag'. error from above statement

Answer (score 0):

```
If the response in json format then you can write directly
this.http.method(url, option).pipe(map((this.handelResponse))

handelResponse(res: Response){
    data = res.json;
    // do whatever you want
    return data // or return your object
}
```