# How to receive a ResponseEntity after successfull delete request

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot, http

After deleting an Entity in my database, I'm returning a ResponseEntity from my Backend (SpringBoot) to my Frontend (Angular 10).
Therefore I make this HTTP request in my Angular:

```
this.http.delete<ResponseEntity<string>>(this.productsPath + '/' + id).subscribe(data => console.log(data.statusCode + data.body));
```

And to receive the response, I created a ResponseEntity interface:

```
interface ResponseEntity<T> {
headers: { [headerName: string]: string },
body: T,
statusCode: "OK" | "SERVER_ERROR" | "BAD_REQUEST", //etc
statusCodeValue: "200" | "500" | "400" | "404" //etc
}
```

Now in SpringBoot this is my delete function, which is working as it's supposed to be:

```
@DeleteMapping(value = "/products/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<String> deleteProduct(@PathVariable String id) {
    try {
        productService.deleteProduct(Long.parseLong(id));
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("Product deleted successfully.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Product doesn't exist in Database.");
    }
}
```

My problem is in the Angular code I suppose, I don't really know how to get the Response from Spring?
Deleting the Entity works, but the response that I log to the console in Angular is always `null`, so I get an Error: `ERROR TypeError: data is null`

Edit: This SO question was why I used the interface method: [How to cast observable response to local object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075816/how-to-cast-observable-response-to-local-object)

Comment: I  could see a semicolon , is it typo before .subscribe

Comment: Sorry, you're right, but that typo was not in my code, only in my SO question, so that wasn't it.

Comment: Check the network tab to see whats actually being sent to the client in the response.  I don't know SpringBoot, but it sounds like the data you are sending back to the client is not what you think it is.

Comment: So you have to have mulitple checkpoints to decode the issue . 1. Check what is going in the request , is it in right format and is backend server receiving it without issues?
2. You need to check the before the response is sent from the backend how does the data look like ?
3. When the response comes from the backend , do a console.log() and check what are you getting .